# Is it possible to compile ImageMagick with custom libxml2 on the Mac

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, imagemagick, configure

It always seems to pick up the version from /usr/lib and there doesn't seem to be a ./configure parameter to override it.

./configure --prefix=$PREFIX --with-quantum-depth=8 --disable-installed --without-x --without-perl --enable-static --disable-shared --with-jpeg --with-tiff CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS" LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS" CFLAGS="$CFLAGS" --disable-openmp --disable-openmp-slow

Thanks,
Rui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, an installation of `libxml2` includes a configuration script `xml2-config` that users of the library use to find the correct paths to its components and other build info.  The Apple-supplied version of libxml2 has `xml2-config` in `/usr/bin`.  If you've installed another version of `libxml2`, make sure your $PATH is set such that its `xml2-config` will be found first by the ImageMagick configure script: so ensuring most likely one of `/usr/local/bin`, `/opt/local/bin` (MacPorts), or `/sw/bin` (Fink) comes before `/usr/bin` on $PATH.

A simpler solution might be to just let MacPorts install it all for you:

```
$ sudo port install ImageMagick
```

Comment: Well, I found out the hard way that MacPorts doesn't cross compile (there's a feature request for this). Because I wanted to compile my app for both 10.5 and 10.6 I ended up having to compile all dependency libraries manual like libpng, libtiff, ... BTW, got the libxml2 to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you just manually edit the Makefile that's generated by ./configure?

EDIT: alternatively, there's an XML2_CONFIG environment variable you can set, to point to the xml2-config script for your custom install.